# I can't use Teechart. Installation failed

Tags: delphi-xe, teechart

I'm having a problem using TeeChart W64 in Delphi Tokyo.

It always shows this error on the first launch of Delpho after installation.

For installation I am using the file TeeChartVCLFMX-2023.38-Offline.exe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the updates installed in the IDE at the time of that TeeChart release.

TeeChart release dates:
https://www.steema.com/version_info/vcl

RAD Studio updates dates:
https://github.com/ideasawakened/DelphiKB/wiki/Delphi-Master-Release-List